# ionic can not pass parameter when using $http

Tags: php, angularjs

I face with a problem when I tray to use $http to connect angularJS with my PHP server side script.

my $http looks like this

```
$http.get('http://www.muslimsquare.com/sandbox/user_login.php', {"userID":'123456'}).
                      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available
                        alert(data);
                      }).
                      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                        alert(data)
                      });
```

as you can see I try to pass userID with value 123456 to my server. and my PHP script is like this

```
<?php
echo 'userID is'.$_GET['userID'];
?>
```

It just response the userID back to client.

when I run this code, it show me just

> userID is

no userID return back to client.

what's wrong on my code.

any idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: what does your console say, and does it fire to your server if it does what's the response of the server in the network tab?

Comment: I change my code to use jquery ($.post('http://www.muslimsquare.com/sandbox/user_login.php'), {userID: '12345'}, function(data){ alert(data); }), it works fine but I don't know it still not work with $http in angularJS

Comment: if you only need jquery in your project for this i wouldn't use jquery

Comment: actually I want to use $http but is it not work, I need to use jquery instead.

Comment: look at my answer again @Giffary i edited and think this should work

Answer (score 0):

Here this is how i use the htttp method,

```
                $http({method: 'get', url: 'http://www.muslimsquare.com/sandbox/user_login.php?userID=123456'}).
                  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                    alert(data);
                  }).
                  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    alert(data)
                  });
```

The error isn't in angular it's

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.muslimsquare.com/sandbox/user_login.php?userID=123456. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access. index.html:1
null
```

The server you're trying to connect with has disabled it for other servers to prevent cross scripting, to disable this you need to set the headers in your user_login.php

Add this to the top of your php file

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

And then try [this codepen](http://codepen.io/sjerd/pen/WbboOE)

Comment: Try this at the very top of your php file: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 0):

This http request is async. That means, Try this approach:
Call this in your Service function

```
promise = $http({
                url: "http://your.url.com/service.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {"data":data}
            }).then(function(response) {
                // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                return response.data;
            });
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise;
```

Call the Service in your controller like:

```
Service.getData(data).then(function(returnedData) {
        $scope.data = returnedData;
    });
```

Your returned data from the service is now in $scope.data and will be shown in your frontend with {{data.value}}

Hope this helps

Comment: You need to change your PHP service eventually.

Comment: sorry, It still not work. I change my code to use jquery, it works fine but I don't know it still not work with $http in angularJS

Answer (score 0):

hey your first code was correct although its meant to fetch JSON data.

```
<?php
echo 'userID is'.$_GET['userID'];
?>
```

this will not output json

try this if you have not found the solution yet

```
$userId = $_GET['userID'];

echo '{"userID ":$userId}';
```

then on the fetching side

```
$http.get('test.php', { params:{ "userID": 2, "name": "yourNameIfAny" } }).then(function(resp){
console.log('Success', resp);
// For JSON responses, resp.data contains the result
$scope.conditions = resp.data.userID;
 $ionicPopup.confirm({
 title: 'Json Responce',
 template: resp.data.userID
   });
  confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
 if(res) {
   console.log('You are sure');
 } else {
   console.log('You are not sure');
 }
 });
```